# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: perl

Получаю пост запрос с данными в кодировке utf-8 и записываю их в бд, но все данные в бд должны храниться в cp1251 кодировке, в итоге те данные которые поступают пост запросом и заносятся в бд выгледят в виде вопросиков, как в perl'е изменять кодировку поступаемых данных (или проще говоря, как поменять кодировку строки на cp1251) ?

Comment: Какая БД? А то, возможно, все решается просто заданием кодировки соединения?...

Comment: да ричём тут бд... всё в порядке там, мне нужна именно кодировка cp1251, у меня всё в кодировке cp1251, кроме тех данных которые пост запросом передаются, вот их и нужно в cp1251 перекодировать

Comment: БД при том, что конвертация utf8 в 1251 может привести к потере данных.

Comment: просто если у меня кодировка файла (primer.pl) utf-8 то вылазиет ошибка Internal Server Error

Comment: Это уже о чём-то другом совсем...

Answer (score 1):

Есть модуль Encode и его одноименная функция encode. Конвертируй строку в cp-1251 и только после добавляй в базу. Проверь, c какой кодировкой сопоставляются данные в базе, она должна быть тоже указана, как cp-1251. И да, ещё проверь флаг mysql_enable_utf, при подключения к базе из скрипта его могут принудительно поднимать, чего делать не надо в твоем случае.

Comment: Encode::encode() нельзя использовать для перекодировки, она совсем для другого вообще-то.

Answer (score 0):

`Text::Iconv`, `Convert::Cyrillic`, даже `Encode::from_to` сгодится, куча вариантов. Но это очень плохая идея :(

Answer (score 0):

А что вы будете делать с символами, отсутствующими в CP1251? Может, лучше всё-таки хранить данные в базе в UTF-8?

Если база — MySQL, то можно осуществлять перекодирование средствами самой СУБД: MySQL (если это не древний 3.23.*) позволяет хранить данные в одной кодировке (и в CP1251), а общение между сервером и клиентом вести в другой. Переключить кодировку, в которой передаются данные, можно различными способами, в том числе командой [`SET NAMES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html):

```
-- Передаваемые данные — в UTF-8
SET NAMES utf8;
```